# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre atributos atomic y nonatomic?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UITextField *txtTelefono;
@property(atomic, retain) UITextField *txtTelefono;
@property(retain) UITextField *txtTelefono;
```

¿Cual es la diferencia en estas tres declaraciones?
¿Qué significa una propierdad `nonatomic` o `atomic`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Al indicar en las propiedades `atomic` o `nonatomic`:

**Atomic**    = thread safery.(seguridad en el hilo).

**Nonatomic** = no thread safery.(sin seguridad en el hilo).

**Atomic**    = menos eficiente que nanotomic en terminoas de velocidad.

**Nonatomic** = mas eficiente que atomic en terminoas de velocidad.

**cuando usar:**

`Atomic` -> cuando se encuentre en un entorno que maneje multithread y estas puedan ser accedidas desde varios hilos.

`Nonatomic` -> cuando usted este seguro que no se va a acceder desde varios hilos y estos puedan generar con sus accesos inconsitencias en los datos, sea al aplicar cambios sobre ellos como al recuperarlos.

---

Si hacemos una llamada al un metodo `get` para una propiedad para obtener los valores del objeto y un instante despues otro `hilo/Thread` de nuestra aplicación, hace una llamada al metodo `set` para esa misma propiedad.

Aplicando lo anterior en un contexto en el que ha leido parte del objeto, y simultaneamente (a la misma "vez") se han realizado modificaciones es posible que el resultado que obtengamos al final tengan en los datos errores o sea inconsistentes, dependiendo de si esta es `atomic` o `nonatomic`.

Si en la propiedad se ha indicado atomic, o no (pues atomic es la opcion asignada por defecto), se garantizaria que el metodo `get` obtuviera todos los  datos originales, antes de que otro `hilo/Thread` efectuara cambios en dicho objeto.

Es posible y se consigue deteniendo el proceso de la llamda al `set` en `CPU` hasta que termine el `get` ejecutado.

Otra diferncia es que nonatomic no detiene el hilo con lo cual no produce pausas en la `CPU` y el rendimiento de la aplicacion no se ve afectado por ello haciendola mas "rapida" con el uso de nanotomic.

Answer (score 0):

Atomic y Nonatomic

Por defecto todas las propiedades son Atomic. Esto significa que los métodos de acceso aseguran que un valor es siempre totalmente asignado u obtenido, incluso cuando los métodos de acceso son invocados de forma simultánea desde hilos diferentes.

Puedes utilizar Nonatomic para especificar que los métodos de acceso devuelvan un valor directamente, sin ninguna garantía sobre lo que suceda si ese mismo valor es accedido de forma simultánea desde diferentes hilos.

Por esta razón, es más rápido para acceder a una propiedad nonatomic que una atomic.